# Asymptotic analysis for a double integral related to Airy functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables, mp.mathematical-physics, asymptotics, special-functions

Let $Ai(x,y)$ be the Airy kernel which is given by
\begin{equation}\label{equ2.12}
Ai(x,y)=
 \begin{cases}
 \dfrac{Ai(x)Ai'(y)-Ai(y)Ai'(x)}{x-y}, & x\ne y, \\
 Ai'(x)^2-xAi(x)^2 & x=y. \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Here $Ai(x)$ denotes the standard Airy function
\begin{align*}
Ai(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\mathcal{C}}{e^{x\cdot t+t^3/3}\,\mathrm dt},
\end{align*}
where  $\mathcal{C}$ is a contour running from $\infty e^{- i \pi /3}$ to $\infty e^{ i \pi /3}$, or any other contour which can be deform from this one such that $Re(t^3) \to -\infty$ along the contour.
Using the relation
\begin{align}\label{equ2.13}
Ai(x,y)=\int_0^{\infty}{Ai(t+x)Ai(t+y)\,\mathrm dt},
\end{align}
we have the following double integral representation of the Airy kernel
\begin{align*}
Ai(x, y)=\frac{1}{(2\pi i)^2}\int_{-\mathcal{C}}\mathrm dt\int_{\mathcal{C}}\mathrm ds\, \frac{e^{x\cdot s+s^3/3}}{e^{y\cdot t+t^3/3}}\cdot\frac{1}{s-t},
\end{align*}

Now let $\cdots<-\lambda_{k}<\cdots<-\lambda_1<0$ be the zeroes of the Airy function $Ai(x)$ and let $\cdots<-\mu_{k}<\cdots<-\mu_1<0$ be the zeroes of  $Ai'(x)$ respectively. Choose large enough and close $\lambda_{k}$, $\mu_{j}$ satisfying
$$
|\lambda_k-\mu_j|\sim \frac{\lambda_k^{-\frac12}}{|k-j|}.
$$
Then one can obtain
$$
A(k, j)\triangleq\frac{|Ai(-\lambda_k, -\mu_j)|}{\sqrt{Ai(-\lambda_k, -\lambda_k)}\cdot \sqrt{Ai(-\mu_j, -\mu_j)}}\approx \frac{1}{2|k-j|}
$$
Now I need to deal with a more complicated form than the Airy kernel. More precisely, consider
\begin{align*}
I(x, y)=\frac{1}{(2\pi i)^2}\int_{-\mathcal{C}}\mathrm dt\int_{\mathcal{C}}\mathrm ds\, \frac{e^{x\cdot s+s^3/3}}{e^{y\cdot t+t^3/3}}\cdot\frac{1}{s-t}\cdot\frac{2e^{-2(s-t)}}{1-e^{-(s-t)}}.
\end{align*}
This can be seen as a "perturbation" of the Airy kernel. I hope to understand the asymptotic behavior of the form
$$
T(k, j)\triangleq\frac{|I(-\lambda_k, -\mu_j)|}{\sqrt{Ai(-\lambda_k, -\lambda_k)}\cdot \sqrt{Ai(-\mu_j, -\mu_j)}}.
$$
**Question: Is there a good way to evaluate $T(k, j)$  and is there a similar estimate as $A(k, j)$ above?**

I think the key is to evaluate the double integral $I(-\lambda_k, -\mu_j)$. Maybe some kind of saddle point argument is needed but I don't know how to deal with it.

Thanks in advance.